# How to write a CSS Selector for a nested attribute that appears twice?

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors, ui-automation

How do I write a CSS Selector to only retrieve the error message "Enter password"?

```
<div class="input-label-element">
    <input type="text" class="Input--regular is-error" minLength="0" maxLength="120" name="username" errorMessage="Enter username" value>
    <div class="Input-regular Input--help-regular Input--message">Enter username</div>
<div class="input-label-element">
    <input type="text" class="Input--regular is-error" minLength="0" maxLength="120" name="username" errorMessage="Enter password" value>
    <div class="Input-regular Input--help-regular Input--message">Enter password</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target it using the `errorMessage` attribute:

```css
[errorMessage="Enter Password"] {
    /* style */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for that the css [attribute selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```css
input[errorMessage="Enter password"] {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-label-element">
  <input type="text" class="Input--regular is-error" minLength="0" maxLength="120" name="username" errorMessage="Enter username" value>
  <div class="Input-regular Input--help-regular Input--message">Enter username</div>
  <div class="input-label-element">
    <input type="text" class="Input--regular is-error" minLength="0" maxLength="120" name="username" errorMessage="Enter password" value>
    <div class="Input-regular Input--help-regular Input--message">Enter password</div>
```